# Basic js validation

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a beginner at JS and I want to do a basic HTML and JS validation. How can I do it with 2 inputs (number and submit)?

```js
    var edad =  document.getElementById("edad"),
      numero = edad.numero

    function validacion(){
        if (numero >= 18) {
          alert("eres mayor de edad");
        } else {
           alert("eres menor de edad");
        }
    }


  edad.addEventListener("submit", validacion);
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 
     <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="edad">
     <input type="number" name="numero"  class="numero">
     <input type="submit" name="btn" value="enviar" class="btn">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are setting up an event listener on `submit`, which points to a `div`, but a `div` doesn't have a `submit` event.

In addition, you need to get the `value` of the `input`, and compare that, not the `input` element itself.

Also, `edad.numero` is not the proper way to access the `input` element.

Lastly, all data that comes into JavaScript from HTML is a string, so you need to convert it to a number to do math with it.

If you set up a valid listener on a `form` element, and reference the `input` correclty the code will fire:

```js
var edad =  document.getElementById("edad");
var numero = document.querySelector("input[name='numero']");

function validacion(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // prevents the form from submitting
  // The + converts the string to a number
  // And, you must get the value of the input, not the input itself
  if (+numero.value >= 18) {
    alert("eres mayor de edad");
  } else {
    alert("eres menor de edad");
  }
}

edad.addEventListener("submit", validacion);
```

```html
<form id="edad">
  <input type="number" name="numero"  class="numero">
 <input type="submit" name="btn" value="enviar" class="btn">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks i really appreciate it , can you explain me what does it means the query selector and in which cases can in use it and the e.preventdefault  it is more or less i know how to use it but i dont know in which specific cases, thanks

Answer (score 0):

html :

```
<form name="myForm" action="/action_page.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
  Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

js code:

```
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, do not write only code without any explanation